# Force Excel to 2010 to have separate taskbar icons for different workbooks

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I know questions similar to this one have been asked before, but not this one.

I do not want separate windows, just separate taskbar icons that I can cycle through with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, and definitely not separate instances (because in that case I would be unable to properly copy-paste between them).

I need to have the different Excel workbooks as different icons in the taskbar and in the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> menu. I know it is possible (I used to have it that way) but now it has changed and I don't know why.

Comment: Maybe I'm being dense, but what is the difference between "separate windows" and "separate window tabs"? If I can cycle through a set of windows with `ALT+TAB`, to me they're separate windows...

Comment: If you can put them on screen, side by side, they are separate windows. If them, instead, change books on the same window when you cycle with Alt+Tab, there are separate tabs but not different windows.

Comment: Ok, I've never seen the "separate tabs" behaviour you're describing so can't really help, but thanks for explaining.

Comment: Hi Envite, I've proposed an edit that makes your question a little easier to understand, if that correctly describes your problem, please approve it :)

Comment: The edits have been approved, I hope this accurately describes your problem.

Answer (score 1):

After further investigation, it seems like not having the "show all windows in taskbar" option checkbox checked in the settings would cause your problem.

[image: OPTIONS>Advanced>display>show all windows in taskbar]

Comment: I had that option activated. Anyway, I'm still checking. Thanks.

Comment: Could you include a screenshot of the behaviour.  Also, for the time being, you should still be able to se Ctrl+tab to cycle through workbooks.